# Integrating with Pocket Outlook

Tags: windows-mobile

Rather than reinvent the wheel I would like to use Outlook to manage my appointments and sync to Windows Mobile. What options are there for integrating a custom app  with Outlook on the mobile? Ideally Id like to just use standard Outlook to display the appointments rather than write a custom UI however can you integrate custom data in there or have some sort of link from a standard outlook appointment to custom UI elements. I'm thinking open a standard appointment and have a button/link to open additional data stored in SQLCE or something like that.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIM items in pocket outlook each have a property bag, so you can add custom properties to each pim item. (I haven't tried with appointments, but I have added custom properties to contacts, and used them in my own applications)

If you are using .netcf take a look at OutlookSession class, which is the main object for interacting with the pim items.

I'm not sure about customisation of the UI though, as all my changes were done through my own application.

Comment: Thanks Matt,
Can I add custom properties on server and get them across to the device?

Comment: Good question, that's not something I have tried as I have only been manipulating the contacts items on the device.